# Importing ISO 8601 Formatted CSV Dates into Matlab R2014b

Tags: matlab, date, csv

I am trying to import a CSV file with ISO 8601 formatted dates with Matlab R2014b. I am using the CSV import wizard, and am needing to use the custom date formatter, as the ISO 8601 date format is not built into Matlab.

However, Matlab never recognises the date/time data as date/time data. Can anyone resolve this? The documentation doesn't say anything about how items that are not part of the date format (e.g. the 'T') are parsed.

Picking a string directly for conversion works ok.

```
>> datenum('"2008-01-01T00:00:00+13:00"', '"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZZZZZ"')

ans =

   7.3338e+05
```

But the same conversion does not work in the CSV import wizard, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Matlab R2015A CSV Import Wizard]

Any particular reason why it works in the command line but not in the import wizard?

Comment: The "more date formats" link eventually leads you to the help of `datestr`. This might mean that under the hood the import wizard uses `datestr` to convert the data, but the [doc of datestr](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) says "To convert a date string not in a predefined MATLAB® date format, first convert the date string to a date number, using either `datenum` or `datevec`", which might not be possible using the wizard. Have you considered importing manually using a script?

Comment: @AndrasDeak I have but I was hoping to avoid it the import tool seemed so good. Note that running `datestr` on the datenum given above actually gives an incorrect result, at least when I run it.


    >> datestr( datenum('"2008-01-01T00:00:00+13:00"', '"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZZZZZ"'), 31 )
         ans =
         2007-11-30 23:01:00